# Does anyone know the exact location of the following text in the Padma Purana?

Tags: vaishnavism, guru, padma-purana, brahmanas

Does anyone know the exact location of the following text in the Padma Purana?

The text is found [here.](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/4/29/51/)

> ṣaṭ-karma-nipuṇo vipro
>   mantra-tantra-viśāradaḥ
>   avaiṣṇavo gurur na syād
>   vaiṣṇavaḥ śva-paco guruḥ